# What is this function composed of and how is it differentiable?

Tags: functions, derivatives, linear-transformations

[image]

I am talking about the function $G(x,y) = (x,y,g(x,y))$ , in order to show that $G$ is differentiable for all $(x,y)$, we have to show that $G$ is the composite of two differentiable functions, right? But what are the functions when composed together yield $G$?